# Conditional rendering isnt working for Object in LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components

Instead of declaring many variables in JavaScript side, Used Object Approach, but Object rendering isn't working properly. (No error in Apex side,response is coming properly that why not added that code here)

**Here is My Previous Code:**

```
                  <template if:true={conditionNames.cond1}>
                     <!-- Certain Fields -->
                   </template>
                   <template if:true={conditionNames.cond2}>
                      <!-- Certain Fields -->
                   </template>
                   <template if:true={conditionNames.cond3}>
                      <!-- Certain Fields -->
                   </template>
```

### Javascript Side:

```
  import { LightningElement,api,wire} from 'lwc';
 import {getRecord} from 'lightning/uiRecordApi';
 import getWrapperList from '@salesforce/apex/ApexController.getWrapperList';
 export default class LearnTest extends LightningElement {
 @api recordId;
 //Object declared here
 conditionNames = {};
 connectedCallback() {
    this.error = '';
    this.getAccountDetails('SOMEPAGENAME');
}

getAccountDetails(PName) {
    console.log('call');
    getWrapperList({
            acId: this.recordId,
            PageName: PName
        })
        .then(result => {
            let values = result && result.length > 0 ? result[0] : [];
            console.log('account details-->', JSON.stringify(values));
            this.processConditions(values);
            this.error = undefined;

        })
        .catch(error => {
            this.error = 'Unknown error';
            if (Array.isArray(error.body)) {
                this.error = error.body.map(e => e.message).join(', ');
            } else if (typeof error.body.message === 'string') {
                this.error = error.body.message;
            }
        });
}

processConditions(values) {
    console.log('values', JSON.stringify(values));
    this.conditionNames.cond1 = values.account.Type == 'A';
    this.conditionNames.cond2 = values.account.Type == 'B';
    this.conditionNames.cond3 = values.account.Type == 'C';
}}
```

**Solved : Working Code**

HTML Side:

```
                  <template if:true={cond1}>
                     <!-- Certain Fields -->
                   </template>
                   <template if:true={cond2}>
                      <!-- Certain Fields -->
                   </template>
                   <template if:true={cond3}>
                      <!-- Certain Fields -->
                   </template>
```

**Javascript:**

```
     import { LightningElement, api, wire } from 'lwc';
   import {getRecord} from 'lightning/uiRecordApi';
   import getWrapperList from 
  '@salesforce/apex/ApexController.getWrapperList';
    export default class LearnTest extends LightningElement {
  @api recordId;
  //conditionNames = {};  commented object
  
  //Declared 3 Variables: is it possible to avoid too many declaration 
 variable
  cond1;
  cond2;
  cond3;
  
   connectedCallback() {
    this.error = '';
   this.getAccountDetails('SOMEPAGENAME');
 }

getAccountDetails(PName) {
    console.log('call');
    getWrapperList({
        acId: this.recordId,
        PageName: PName
    })
        .then(result => {
            let values = result && result.length > 0 ? result[0] : [];
            console.log('account details-->', JSON.stringify(values));
            this.processConditions(values);
            this.error = undefined;

        })
        .catch(error => {
            this.error = 'Unknown error';
            if (Array.isArray(error.body)) {
                this.error = error.body.map(e => e.message).join(', ');
            } else if (typeof error.body.message === 'string') {
                this.error = error.body.message;
            }
        });
}

  processConditions(values) {
   console.log('values',JSON.stringify(values));
    this.cond1 = values.account.Type =='A';
    this.cond2 = values.account.Type =='B';
    this.cond3 = values.account.Type =='C';
    } }
```

> **Questions**:

1. Whats the issue in Object rendering?
2. Without Object approach, need to declare **many variables** in
   java script side, **whats the best way to reduce the count of variables**

Comment: We don't have enough information to help you. For (1), it should work properly, for (2) use an Object (thus, going back to 1). You've oversimplified your code, and you haven't said what the error was, if any. You need to do some debugging.

Comment: @sfdcfox updated the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your instance variables are reactive (cause rerendering when assigned to). *Their* properties, such as `this.conditionNames.cond1`, are *not* reactive by default. Assigning to `this.conditionNames` would cause a rerender; assigning to `this.conditionNames.cond1` would not.

The section [Observe an Object’s Properties or an Array’s Elements](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.reactivity_fields) of the Lightning Web Components developer guide covers this in some detail with an example that is parallel to yours. Quick summary:

> There is one use case for @track. When a field contains an object or an array, there’s a limit to the depth of changes that are tracked. To tell the framework to observe changes to the properties of an object or to the elements of an array, decorate the field with @track.

> Without using @track, the framework observes changes that assign a new value to the field. If the new value is not === to the previous value, the component rerenders.

So,

> Whats the issue in Object rendering?

You need to annotate `conditionNames` with `@track` to make its properties reactive.

> Without Object approach, need to declare many variables in java script side, whats the best way to reduce the count of variables

I don't think there's really an answer to this as such. It's possible that this indicates your component is trying to do too many things and you need to factor into smaller components that each manage a single concern, but it may simply be that you have the right amount of logic for what you're trying to achieve. There's not enough detail in the question for me to feel confident being more specific.

Comment: Thanks David. In this example, Object Approach is fine? Instance variable approach is fine?

Comment: They're both fine so long as you use @track where you need it

Comment: Thanks david...